# Appveyor failing randomly on goolgetest runs

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, mingw, googletest, appveyor

I have been trying to get four builds to pass on a CI (each combination of 64/32bit and MSVC/MinGW). I've tested each one on my local machine with no issues. When they are built and tested on Appveyor, they will sometimes pass, and sometimes not. For example:

- a build that passes all but [32 bit MSVC](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nealkruis/kiva/build/1.0.102)
- a build that passes all but [32 bit MinGW](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nealkruis/kiva/build/1.0.107)
- a build that passes only [64 bit MinGW](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nealkruis/kiva/build/1.0.104)

Most of these are built off the same commit. The changes between any different commits should have absolutely no effect on the build...only a "timeout" call before running the tests.

Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Cross post on the Appveyor forum [here](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/6053-google-test-cases-failing-randomly-even-on-the-same-build).

Comment: You have filled a bugreport for appveyor, so everyone who involved into it will see that. Others unlikely find this question solvable: there are a number of possible reasons why same project may work on one machine and doesn't work on other.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Embarrassingly, the cause was an uninitialized variable. Crazy that the behavior can be so radically different from build to build. And even between running google test natively and through CTEST.